# Cut-off of rank-size distribution

Tags: distributions, quantiles

How do you calculate the cut-off of any rank-size distribution, which splits the distribution so that the top x% categories contain 1-x% of observations? The classical example is the Pareto principle, whereby the top 20% have 80% of observations. A Pareto distribution puts x at 20%, but I want to calculate x for any given distribution.

Comment: Welcome to [stats.se]!  Please take a moment to view our [tour].  It looks like you answered you question unless you have a question beyond the 80-20 rule.

Comment: @Tavrock I want to be able to find the x for any rank-size distribution, if that wasn't clear. It could be anything between 0% and 50%, depending on the shape of the distribution.

Comment: @Tavrock Some distributions could be thick-headed, so that the cut-off would be low, e.g. "the top 2% categories contain 98% of observations". (A Pareto distribution is thick-headed.) Or a distribution could be thick-tailed, e.g. "the top 49% categories contain 51% of observations" means the distribution is almost flat.

Comment: It gets confusing because you are asking about the Pareto distribution, but it sounds like you really want inverse distribution functions where you are able to find the $x$ value for a given set of parameter values (such as $\alpha$ and $\beta$ for a two-parameter Weibull or $\sigma$ and $\mu$ for a Gaussian distribution) and a desired percentile ranking value.

Comment: @Tavrock Now you've got me confused. I've removed my made-up "Pareto-style". I'm working with Zipf distributions (of cities). The distributions change every year and I'd like to compare the level of concentration from year to year. My idea is to use that x as a simple metric of concentration.

Comment: @Tavrock This is new for me, so I don't know if I'm making myself clear. I'm working from actual data, not from probability functions.

Comment: Here's a [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43012303/7114709) to get this in R.